# Using ApplescriptObjC to convert color spaces of an image using NSColorSpace and iccProfileData

Tags: applescript-objc, color-profile, nscolorspace

I have some code that will change an images colorspace from RGB to a GenericCMYK profile. I would like to be able to use an ICC Profile to convert the image to a CMYK colorspace. There is a way to do this in Photoshop, but the process takes too much of a users time when you are dealing with 100's of images, I am trying to create an AppleScript droplet that will do this for them.

I have already looked at the page for NSColorspace and there looks like there is a way to do this. I just have no idea how to convert this Objective-C into ApplescriptObjC. Here are the two references to the ICC Profiles in NSColorSpace:
init?(iccProfileData: Data)
Initializes and returns an NSColorSpace object given an ICC profile.
var iccProfileData: Data?
The ICC profile data from which the receiver was created.

Here is the code I have thanks to Shane at Macscripter.net:

```
set theImage to (current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfURL:theInput)
    set imageRep to (theImage's representations()'s objectAtIndex:0)
    set targetSpace to current application's NSColorSpace's genericCMYKColorSpace()
    set bitmapRep to (imageRep's bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace:targetSpace renderingIntent:(current application's NSColorRenderingIntentPerceptual))
    set theProps to (current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObjects:{1.0, true} forKeys:{current application's NSImageCompressionFactor, current application's NSImageProgressive})
    set jpegData to (bitmapRep's representationUsingType:(current application's NSJPEGFileType) |properties|:theProps)
    set colorSpace to bitmapRep's colorSpaceName() as text
    (jpegData's writeToURL:theOutput atomically:true)
```

I just need to figure out how to include the ICC Profile as a part of the CMYK conversion process that happens I believe on this line of code:

```
set targetSpace to current application's NSColorSpace's genericCMYKColorSpace()
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the NSColorSpace documentation in Swift.  AppleScriptObjC is an Objective-C bridge, so it makes more sense viewing the documentation in Objective-C (the language can be set in the page header), where your snippet becomes

```
set targetSpace to current application's NSColorSpace's alloc's initWithICCProfileData:iccData
```

where iccData is the ICC profile data you are going to use.

Comment: Yes I should have looked more carefully at the documentation. I always look at just the Objective-C documentation, so I don't know how it switched back. Thanks for pointing it out. And Especially big thanks for translating that line into AppleScriptObjC for me!

Comment: So that line of code crashes Script Editor, Script Debugger, and as a standalone Script application. I found the following online that makes it seem as though the ICC profile needs to be read into a variable and that passed to the initWithICCProfileData.
NSString* labProfilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lab" ofType:@"icc"];
  NSData* labProfileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:labProfilePath];
  NSColorSpace* labCS = [[NSColorSpace alloc] initWithICCProfileData:labProfileData];

Comment: Ok I partly answered my followup question I think, the code for reading and using the ICCProfile data is:
set theFile to POSIX file "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic CMYK Profile.icc"
set theData to current application's NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile:theFile
It works with that generic profile, but it crashes with ones from Gracol for some reason. The Gracol Profiles can be downloaded here if anyone wants to play with them:
http://connect.idealliance.org/HigherLogic/System/DownloadDocumentFile.ashx?DocumentFileKey=52331ee3-301b-e6b1-7159-9b45541ab420&forceDialog=1

Comment: And then just like that... POOF, the crashing was gone. Not sure what I did, but it works for me now!

Comment: I think it might just be an issue with those particular profiles.  I tested your exact script with several different profiles without any problems, but most of those Gracol profiles crashed for me as well.